# Graph results using canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, graph, tkinter

I have written my code and I want to graph the amount of times each dice is rolled. This isn't working how can I do it. I don't want to use any graphing packages.

```
import random
import time

name="JORDAN SUMMERS RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR ASSIGNMENT"
by="## Created by Jordan Summers ##"
date="@ 31.03.2015"
symbol="_"*50
bos=""*5
warning = "Please enter a number, i.e. 1. Not 'one'."
information=""" YOU WILL CHOOSE HOW MANY TIMES TO ROLL THE DICE,
ONCE ROLLED THE PROGRAM WILL PRINT THE NUMBERS, THEN IT WILL SORT THE NUMBERS
HIGHEST TO LOWEST. """
print("{:^80}\n{:^80}\n{:^80}\n{:^80}\n{:^80}\n{}".format(name,by,date,warning,symbol,bos,))


rolllist = []

total = 0



dice = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? "))
if dice >50:
    print("Please enter a lower number") 
else:

    for i in range(dice):
        rolllist.append (random.randint(1,6))
        print ("You rolled a " + str(rolllist[i]))      #Here we are adding the results to the list

    total = sum(rolllist)
    print ("The total of the numbers " + str(total))    #This is calculating the total

    rolllist.sort()
    print ("numbers sorted " + str(rolllist))   #This is sorting the numbers in order of value

    a = rolllist.count(1)
    print ("The number 1 occured " + str(a) + " times." + " It's percentage is ") #Line 34 to line 51 are counting how many times a number occured.

    percent_1 = ((int(rolllist.count(1))/(dice)))
    print(percent_1*100)

    b = rolllist.count(2)
    print ("The number 2 occured " + str(b) + " times." + " It's percentage is ")

    percent_2 = ((int(rolllist.count(2))/(dice)))
    print(percent_2*100)

    c = rolllist.count(3)
    print ("The number 3 occured " + str(c) + " times." + " It's percentage is ")

    percent_3 = ((int(rolllist.count(3))/(dice)))
    print(percent_3*100)

    d = rolllist.count(4)
    print ("The number 4 occured " + str(d) + " times." + " It's percentage is ")

    percent_4 = ((int(rolllist.count(4))/(dice)))
    print(percent_4*100)

    e = rolllist.count(5)
    print ("The number 5 occured " + str(e) + " times." + " It's percentage is ")

    percent_5 = ((int(rolllist.count(5))/(dice)))
    print(percent_5*100)

    f = rolllist.count(6)
    print ("The number 6 occured " + str(f) + " times." + " It's percentage is")

    percent_6 = ((int(rolllist.count(6))/(dice)))
    print(percent_6*100)



    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(root, width = 640, height = 360, bg = "red")
    canvas.pack()

    canvas.create_rectangle(1, 360, 50,(a), fill = "black")
    canvas.create_rectangle(60,360, 100,(b), fill = "blue")
    canvas.create_rectangle(110,360, 150,(c), fill = "yellow")
    canvas.create_rectangle(160,360, 200,(d), fill = "white")
    canvas.create_rectangle(210,360, 250,(e), fill = "orange")
    canvas.create_rectangle(260,360, 300,(f), fill = "pink")
    root.mainloop()
```

What do I do. I want this to graph, what I'm doing should work. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Note: always write clearly what is the problem. Here, I lost some time finding what it was.
So your first reectangle has y-coordinates 360 and a. And a is always small.
Try something like:

```
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = 640, height = 100, bg = "red")    
    canvas.create_rectangle(1, 100, 50,100 - percent_1 *100, fill = "black")
```

Comment: P.S. Your code could use some refactoring (for loops especially).

Comment: Thank you so much, BTW what co-ordinate would i have to change to use the same system only move the new rectangle over so you can see both.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.